# Why a variable inside a private inner class can't get value of a private variable that has value from AsynCallback method in Gwt?

Tags: java, gwt, gwtp

I found this very weird behavior in Gwt.

I have a simple TestPresenter.java that have 2 buttons. Button 1 get data from DB and return value via Asyncallback method. Button 2 is to retrieve that value from a private inner class.

```
private String test1;
private String test2;
private AsyncCallback<GetArticleResult> getArticleCallback=new AsyncCallback<GetArticleResult>(){
@Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            loadingPresenter.hide();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(GetArticleResult result) {
            test1=result.getVal();
            test2="123";

        }
};
private class  InlineHTMLContextMenuHandler implements ContextMenuHandler {



        @Override
        public void onContextMenu(ContextMenuEvent event) {
            System.out.println(test1);
            System.out.println(test2);
        }
}
```

Now, I click the Button 1 first & it get Data from DB, then I click the button 2. Then  I get the output: `test1=Null; test2="123";` when debugging the `test1` show real value, not `null`. For `test1` variable, If I access it from a method normally then it will be fine but if accessing it from private inner class then I can't get its value.

What wrong? This so weird?

Comment: What version of GWT are you using? If not the latest, try to upgrade. Solved some issues in the past for me. Also, are you sure that result.getVal() is not null when not debugging? Put a println in the onSuccess just to be sure.

Comment: i am using GwtP 2.4 or 2.5 couldn't remember

Comment: yes, I am sure, it return a value

Comment: can you include the full source for the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a test with GWT 2.5.1 and the problem did not happen. Most likely your problem is in the class GetArticleResult.

Here is the code I used:

```
private String test1 = null;
private String test2 = null;

private AsyncCallback<GetArticleResult> callback = new AsyncCallback<GetArticleResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
        Window.alert(throwable.getClass().getName() + " - " + throwable.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(GetArticleResult s) {
        test1 = s.msg;
        test2 = "123";
        Window.alert(test1 + " - " + test2);
    }
};

private class MyValueChangeHandler implements ValueChangeHandler<String> {
    @Override
    public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> stringValueChangeEvent) {
        Window.alert(test1 + " - " + test2);
    }
}
```

And my GetArticleResult is very simple:

```
public class GetArticleResult implements IsSerializable {

    public String msg;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i knew now, cos of my coding err, i call the ansyn many time on the same method so the second call overrided the value

Comment: Then you could cancel the pending requests (com.google.gwt.http.client.Request.cancel), so they don't call onSuccess when they are finished.